# conditional jumps -- comparing c code to assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I am trying to compare a c function code to the equivalent of the assembly and kind of confused on the conditional jumps

[image]

I looked up `jl` instruction and it says jump if < but the answer to the question was `>=` Can someone explain why is that?

Comment: Fow which processor type is this assembly language? Motorola 68000?

Comment: `<` and `>=` are each others inversions. The former (with `<`) is probably less or faster instructions, so it's an optimization issue.

Comment: It's x86 assembly intel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my understanding, the condition is inverted, but the logic is the same; the C source defines

> if the condition is satisfied, execute the following block

whereas the assembly source defines

> if the condition is violated, skip the following block

which means that the flow of execution will be the same in both implementations.

Comment: funny enough, in this case not the condition is changed. but the order of operators. both conditions is "if less", in asm it's " jl " (same as the " if <"  in the C code), but not `a < b` is compared, but %edx( holding b) with a

Answer (score 2):

In essence, what this assembly is doing, is executing your condition as you set it, but using negative logic.

Your condition says:

> If a is smaller then b, return x. Otherwise, return y.

What the assembly code says (simplified):

> Move y into the buffer for returning. Move b into a different buffer.
>   If a is bigger then b, jump ahead to the return step. Then y is
>   returned. If a is not bigger then b, continue in the program. The next
>   step assigns x to the return buffer. The step after that returns as
>   normal.

The outcome is the same, but the process is slightly different.

Comment: You have lost 'a' in your explanation

Comment: @MichałWalenciak Thank you. I amended the answer. I mis-wrote a for x there.

Answer (score 1):

the assembly does, line by line (code not included, because you posted it as image):

```
foo:
    return_value (eax) = y; // !!!
    temporary_edx = b;      // x86 can't compare memory with memory, so "b" goes to register
    set_flags_by(a-b);      // cmp does subtraction and discards result, except flags
    "jump less to return"   // so when a < b => return y (see first line)
    return_value (eax) = x;
    return
```

so to make that C code do the same thing, you need:

```
if (a >= b) { return x; } else { return y; }
```

BTW, see how easy it is to flip:

```
if (a < b) { return y; } else { return x; }
```

So there's no point to translate `jl` into "less" into C, you have to track down each branch, what really happens, and find for each branch of calculation the correct C-side calculation, and then "create" the condition in C to get the same calculation on both sides, so this task is not about "translating" the assembly, but about deciphering the asm logic + rewriting it back in C. Looks like you sort of completely missed the point and expected you can get away with some simple "match pattern" translation, while you have to work it out fully.